# EACCESS error on port 443 within Azure Function request

Tags: node.js, azure, https, azure-functions

I am making an https request towards a server, which requires TLS 1.2.

Making a GET request to that server works on my browser, in CURL, but in my Azure Function I get this error :

```
Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
code: 'EACCES',
errno: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 443
```

This request is done within an azure function. I don't have a custom domain for my azure function, therefor it should use their SSL no ? What am I missing ?

Here is my request:

```
var options = {
        url: 'https://somesite.ca/somepath/Services/something.asmx/GetTrustedAutorizationTicket',
        qs: {UserName: 'username', Domain: '', Password: 'pwd', ClearText: 'true'},
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        }
    }

    var req = https.get(options, function(res) {...
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `url` in `options`. You are looking for `hostname` and `path`.

E.g.

```js
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'somesite.ca',
  port: 443,
  path: '/somepath/Services/something.asmx/GetTrustedAutorizationTicket',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  ...
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't even notice I wasn't using it properly.